# Euler Maclaurin formula for functions with singularities

Tags: integration, summation, singularity, euler-maclaurin

Is there a version of the Euler Maclaurin formula for treating functions having singularities ?

for example $$ \sum_{k=0}^{99} \sum_{x=0}^{n} \frac{1}{\frac{k}{100} + \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + d})}{100} - 1} $$

Note: I know there's a partial sum formula for this but it includes the Polygamma of negative values which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: which singularity ? , i mean there are no poles on the summand or integrand for the Euler mac laurin summation

Comment: Laurent series is what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoseGarcia made a typo, I've edited the question.

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin requires the function to be continuous in the interval of summation, so it is possible to apply the formula to subintervals in which the function is continuous.

Comment: What is is that you are actually trying to estimate? The sum you've posted can be computed without using the Euler-Maclaurin Formula. Do you want to estimate the sum as $n$ ($99$ in the question) grows?

Comment: @robjohn no I actually need the double summation say k from 0 to 99 and then x from 0 to k. But the summation formula of k is bringing out Polygamma of negative reals for x which I find hard to sum.

Comment: So what you really want is $$\sum_{k=0}^{99}\sum_{x=0}^k\frac1{\frac{k}{100}+x-1}$$ Unfortunately, the sum in the question won't help with that sum because the sum in $x$ needs to be taken first. Did you mean instead that you want to sum $x$ from $0$ to $n$?

Comment: That is, perphaps you want instead $$\sum_{x=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{99}\frac1{\frac{k}{100}+x-1}$$ That sum has the problem that $\frac10$ is one of the summands.

Comment: @robjohn yeah the last comment is what I want, but what if we take x from 1 to n and x is changed to $$ \sqrt{(x^2 + d)}$$.

Comment: @robjohn yeah the last comment is what I want, but what if we take x from 1 to n and x is changed to $$ \frac{\sqrt{(x^2 + d)}}{100}$$.

Comment: Now that you seem to have a clearer picture of what you want to ask, perhaps you could edit your question to make the question clearer.

Comment: @robjohn I've edited the main question